# L1 Misses in Gem5 not matching L2 Hits+Misses

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, gem5

I am implementing implementing a simple cache hierarchy with 64KB L1 Dcache, 64KB L1 Icache and a unified 4MB L2 cache (all exclusive).

I ran CPU2006 sjeng benchmark and I got the following stats:

- system.cpu.dcache.overallMisses::total        2368294                       # number of overall misses (Count)
- system.cpu.icache.overallMisses::total            564                       # number of overall misses (Count)
- system.l2.overallHits::total                       36                       # number of overall hits (Count)
- system.l2.overallMisses::total                   3279                       # number of overall misses (Count)

I was assuming that the total L1 miss should be equal to L2 Hit+Miss, but there is a huge difference in the numbers. Can someone please help me on how to relate them.

Comment: I was going to say perhaps multiple loads on the same cache line that miss in L1d could all be waiting for the same line from L2, so L2 only sees one miss for several load instructions that miss in L1d.  But that can't explain such an extreme a ratio.

Comment: The relationship between L1 and L2 cache misses is more complex than a simple equality. You are mentioning that there is no L3 cache attached in your configuration. To help me understand your stats, could you please dump all of your stat files here.

Comment: I agree with @Peter Cordes. The high number of L1D misses could be due to accessing the same block line (different bytes). one way to find out that is by dumping all L1D clock addresses to see if they hit the same block line.